# How to view blueprint hierarchy in Tridion 2009

Tags: 2009, blueprint

Tridion 2011 has a nice feature of viewing blueprint hierarchy. How can I do the same in Tridion 2009?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 2011 and up you have the `BluePrint Hierarchy` option under the `BluePrinting` context menu, in 2009 this was part of the `Where Used` option in your context menu.

Opening the `Where Used` in 2009 you will see an additional tab called `BluePrint hierarchy` which shows the exact same information as you have in 2011 and up. It really is only the location which has changed.

Answer (score 2):

I thought this was done exactly the same way.

I don't have a version to check but  certain you can get it when either right clicking the publication item and viewing from there, or perhaps you have to view the properties first and there is a blueprint hierarchy tab/ option.

I'm doubting if it's possible for items like in 2011 as I don't remember seeing it in the item diog window.

Not really an answer but might lead you in the right way.

Comment: Yep. It's exactly the same way.